# ASP timer Control is refreshing the whole page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webforms

I have a ASP timer control which is supposed to run every three minutes. Although I kept the Timer control in an update panel, it is refreshing the whole page every time it runs.

Is there any it only refresh the particular section of the page, not the whole page?

```
<div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="300000" >
                </asp:Timer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>               
    </div>
```

Comment: usually it will update only update panel, may be you have some problem with your Script Manager..

Answer (score 4):

```
        <asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="200" ontick="function" />

        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">

            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
            </Triggers>

            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" id="label1" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="300000">
    </asp:Timer>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: missing closing timer tag but other than that it's the good answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use UpdatePanel Triggers.  [Conditional Update Panels with triggers](http://weblogs.asp.net/ruslan/archive/2008/02/07/ajax-updatepanel-triggers-conditional-update-mode.aspx), and msdn source. [Updatepanel with Triggers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="300000"> </asp:Timer>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use update panel and add all the control's inside update panel which you don't want to be refreshed or postback by any event