# stop page from reloading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a timer inside an UpdatePanel that refreshes the panel every second. The problem is that everytime that the timer event is fired the page is reloaded and all the variables are reinitialized.

How can I stop the page from reloading everytime the the timere event fires?

My Asp code is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
    <Triggers>
    </Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Interval="1000">
                  </asp:Timer>
                  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                  </asp:ScriptManager>
            </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**EDIT:**

My Page Load code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("D:\\server\\a.txt"))
        {
            logged = File.ReadAllText("D:\\server\\a.txt");
        }
        if (logged != "1")
        {
            //update some text labels
        }
        else
        {
            Timer1.Interval = 1000;
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
     }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260455/asp-timer-control-is-refreshing-the-whole-page

Comment: Post your `Page_Load` code.

Comment: You have several tag closure errors in the code you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UpdatePanel`s limit client side updating and reduce network traffic but they still generate a full server side update. A client side timer that causes a postback will cause a full server side refresh. You will need to preserve your variables so consider using ViewState.

If you want to eliminate a server side update, you will need to intercept the postback and completely handle your client side update on the client.