# How to add div tag into while loop using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, while-loop

I created a webpage called `profile.aspx` like that.

```
<div id="div1">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" >
        //Name
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">
        //Satutes 
    </asp:Label>
</div>
```

And this is the `profile.aspx.cs` file for this file

This select query

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name,Status FROM [ProfileStatusPhoto] 
           WHERE Email = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "'";
```

This is while loop

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    status += dr["Status"].ToString();
    name += dr["name"].ToString();
    Label1.Text = name;
    Label2.Text = status;
}
```

I have no idea,How to join this loop above div tags?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your SQL. Consider using an ORM such as entity framework.

Comment: Suggesting entity framework to fix an sql injection issue is like suggesting a cannon to get rid of a fly.

Comment: Why "that"? Why did you go with the div and only the div? If I am correct I think you want that portion to repeat, each time showing the corresponding data.

Comment: @JanVanHerck the poster clearly isn't that experienced with SQL, so using an orm which precludes any chance of a SQL injection attack is sensible. Frankly the problem in this case is not the fly (the bug) but the wall (the coder). Therefore a cannon is an appropriate tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something lke this

```
<div id="container" runat="server">

</div>
```

on you page load

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name,Status FROM [ProfileStatusPhoto] WHERE Email = @Email";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Session["Email"].ToString());
while (dr.Read())
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = 
    new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");    
    Label nameLabel = new Label();
    status += dr["Status"].ToString();
    name += dr["name"].ToString();
    nameLabel.Text = name;
    Label statusLabel = new Label();
    statusLabel.Text = status;
   div.Controls.Add(nameLabel);
   div.Controls.Add(statusLabel);
   container.Controls.Add(div);
}
```

So you will have a container where for each pair `name-status`  you will create a div with two labels

load these data only if it isn't a POstBack

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    //load data
}
```

Comment: I pasted this code on my cs file, and there is a error for cmd.parameters. What is the namespase for cmd.parameters?

Comment: This is the error

Error 7 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'parameters' and no extension method 'parameters' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: thanks, i used that code, i added it to page load method, but when i am run this page, there have IndexOutOfRangeException for  name += dr["name"].ToString(); what should i do now.

Comment: chnage it to dr["Name"]. If it doesn't work check first if it isn't DbNULL

Comment: it's working but it has some problems.        i typed an status and click the post button to post. but that status was not displayed, Then i refreshed the page, Then i could see it. Then i again enter a another status and refreshed the page, Then it was posted likes this                                                                      1st time===>Prabth Kanishkahi                                               2nd timeI sayed hello===> prabath KanishkaPrabath Kanishkahihello could you tell me how to fix this

Comment: load controls only `if !Page.IsPostBack`

Comment: If my answer solve your problem remember to mark it as accepted to avoid that the question remains unanswered

Comment: not yet friend, i used IsPostBack also as u said, but it posting likes this, Please see this screenshots [1st i say hi](https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-0/10382729_615983818507134_7629598189703268546_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&oh=986008501879831ae4625d01ce95a7d9&oe=5503914E) [2nd time i say hello](https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-0/1456753_615983821840467_926687506400648266_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&oh=46b6b24316389f97c0242a7d728fb34b&oe=54FB791C) Please tell me how to fix this bugs,

Comment: Where is the problem? I saw a name and a status (if the status is hi) you just need to style the labels with this command `nameLabel.CssClass="One Valid Css Class";`

Comment: [This is what](https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10405635_1500135106942732_3405316026992011431_n.jpg?oh=7a5f0f9013284e7b59204d5a1abafc9c&oe=5501AED9) i want friend,When i am posting these, those should be displayed like that, do u have a code for this?

Comment: My friend I think that my answer should be accepted and you should ask a new question about "How style your div" and then I can help you one more time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want update your page dynamically over time you should place a timer in `.aspx` file and do page refresh or perform AJAX call and create div with JavaScript.

Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260455/asp-timer-control-is-refreshing-the-whole-page) if you want to make a partial update with timer control.